# how to create row level trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have one table in the `hr` schema called `employee`, I need to create row level trigger on this table so that whenever I try to update salary on employee table I ensure that salary not to be decreased!

I have tried this one but I get an error:

> Error report: ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here 01748.
>   00000 - "only simple column names allowed here

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER salary_dec_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE OF emp.salary
ON emp 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if(:new.salary>:old.salary)
then

update emp set emp.salary=emp.salary+:new.salary where emp.employee_id=:new.employee_id;
else 
rollback;
end if;
END; 
/
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "can't get good result" ?

Comment: i mean I've got run time error dude..Error report:
ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
01748. 00000 -  "only simple column names allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Just specify the column name `salary` and not the qualified column name `emp.salary`. Same applies to `employee_id`

Comment: ya I have tried this too dude...now it is compiled but,when i try to update salary it is giving error!is:Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table HR.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "HR.SAL_UPDATE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.SAL_UPDATE'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: That's tricky.Can you try with an `after` trigger instead of `before`  Because in your case it is trying to read the column value `salary` which is not yet updated.

Comment: In your code you're setting the salary as the sum between the old salary and the new one. You're not just preventing the salary to be updated to a lower one. So if the guy had a salary of 4000 and you update for a salary of 4200 after this he'll have a salary of 8200. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER salary_dec_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE OF salary ON emp 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  if(:new.salary < :old.salary) then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Salary can''t be decreased');
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: This is the correct way to go about it but your answer would be far better if you explained what problem the OP is happening. Namely that you shouldn't (can't in some situations) update the table on which the trigger is based when that is the trigger being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code you're trying that whenever you update a salary for an employee you'll actually sum it with his previous salary, right? And only allow increases in salary, never a decrease.

So why don't you just say `:new.salary = :old.salary + :new.salary`? And skip the rollback, just do `:new.salary = :old.salary`;

If it doesn't work you should try a procedure with an autonomous transaction to do that but that's what a before trigger should allow you to do directly ([check this here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/Changedatainabeforeinsertorupdatetrigger.htm)).